# ng-model can't get value from input in specific method

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wanna check email duplication using ng-keypress.
So I declared ng-model 'usrEmail'.
When it is used in 'register' method, it can bind with input value, , but it can't bind with input value in 'checkDuplication'.

how to solve this problem??

signup.html

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="usrEmail" ng-model="usrEmail" ng-required="true" ng-keyup="checkDuplication()">
...
<button class="btn btn-primary full-width" ng-click="register()">Register</button>
```

signup.js

```
var methods = {
    checkDuplication: function($scope) {
        $scope.usrEmail;
        console.log($scope.usrEmail); // undifined!!!!!!!
        ...
    },
    register: function($scope){
        $scope.user.usrEmail =  $scope.usrEmail; // successfully binded!
        ...
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your signup.js snippet. Where is your controller and module declaration? For this one view, you should have one controller with `$scope` injected once to refer to the same instance within the view/model. I might recommend [John Papa's style guide for AngularJS](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Comment: I declared them bottom of signup.js "angular.module('myModule').controller('signupCtrl', signupCtrl).service('signupService', signupService)" like this. Controller calls service's methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass $scope as argument to Singup.js (controller/service). You should pass your model in markup like `ng-keyup="checkDuplication(usrEmail)"` and use in function like:

```
checkDuplication: function(usrEmail) {
    console.log(usrEmail);
    ...
}
```

Here is a Plunker to assist: https://plnkr.co/edit/bl4Ui3LbDckvrg8XDjxP?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="usr-Email" ng-model="usrEmail" ng-required="true" ng-keyup="checkDuplication()">
```